# Restore Site Assets

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I was viewing the files in the site assets library. I clicked on the edit page option and the library appeared like a `webpart`. Deleted the webpart and saved the page. Now whenever I click on the Site Assets it is showing

> "404 NOT FOUND" error.

I opened the site in designer. The Site Asset library was there with all those files. So I tried to restore it from recycle bin, but it tells that those files already exist in that location. I am using `SharePoint 2010`.

How can I restore the Site Assets library?

Comment: Is your site asset folder in recycle bin or in `all files` ? If it exists in both, take a backup of site assets in `all files`, delete/ rename it, and restore from recycle bin

Comment: Sound to me like you corrupted the default View of the Library, not the Library (and the files) itself. And SharePoint corrupted the link in the QuickLaunch for you so it points to a non existing (404) page. Open SiteAssets via All Site Content